# Invalid object name while running stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure

```
alter PROCEDURE pricing.select_from_table @table_name NVARCHAR(255)
AS  
begin
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name);
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

and I run it through

```
EXECute [pricing].[select_from_table] 'pricing.pricingprod2023_nom3_copy2'
```

I get error
Invalid object name 'pricing.pricingprod2023_nom3_copy2'.`

Even though table exists and I have permissions

I was trying to select all rows from a given database through sql stored procedure and I am expecting all the rows of the table name supplied

Comment: I can't think of a single benefit to doing this over just allowing the user `SELECT` permissions on the tables you expect them to pass to this procedure. About the only thing I can think of is that you've had a demand that there be no direct access to tables in which case this is surely violating the *spirit* if not the *letter* of that demand.

Answer (score 3):

`QUOTENAME` is for each part, not the *entire* path. `QUOTENAME(N'MySchema.MyTable')` results in `N'[MySchema.MyTable]'` which when injected into a dynamic statement results in the **object** named `MySchema.MyTable` on the `USER`s default schema, such as `dbo`: `dbo.[MySchema.MyTable]`.

If you need to provide both the schema and the object name, use 2 parameters:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE pricing.select_from_table @SchemaName sysname,
                                          @TableName sysname
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N';';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
END;
```

Comment: one can also use PARSENAME to get the database / schema / table parts of the table and quote them separately

Comment: @siggemannen please can you give some example (code/link) etc. sorry I am new to sql stored procedure

Comment: @akshenndragarg added in separate answer

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can be a better version:

```
create or alter PROCEDURE spSelectStuff @table_name NVARCHAR(776)
AS  
begin
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + CONCAT(QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@table_name, 3)), '.', QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@table_name, 2)), '.', QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@table_name, 1)));
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END

GO
-- Test code
exec spSelectStuff 'sometable'
exec spSelectStuff 'sys.objects'
exec spSelectStuff 'master.sys.objects'
```

It parses each table part and quotes it separately. I was a bit lazy to add linked server (parsename 4), but i have a feeling you should be able to figure it out if needed.

EDIT: Larnu's version that works from SQL Server 2017:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spSelectStuff2 @table_name nvarchar(776)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + CONCAT_WS(N'.',QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@table_name, 3)), QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@table_name, 2)), QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@table_name, 1)));
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

END;
```

Comment: Hmm, I'd suggest using `CONCAT_WS` here instead. Otherwise you end up with a statement like `FROM ..sometable`, which though valid, isn't good practice.

Comment: good suggestion, this can be a good practice for the OP to polish it up

Comment: As a quick example of my point anyway: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WsSMMsDJ).

Comment: That's actually pretty sweet. Due to old habits, i tend to keep my code to SQL Server 2016 standard, but i added your version too.

Comment: Yeah, I tend (at least on [so]) to tend to assume a fully supported version as a minimum unless advised otherwise; which at the moment is SQL Server 2019+. Though 2022 has *a lot* of new bells and whistles.